# Simple way to get the bundle identifier at runtime in React Native?

Tags: react-native

We've hit a problem that could be solved if we know the bundle identifier at run time in our RN app. We've seen a few libraries but would rather not include a whole library to do this one thing. Is there a simple way to get this information in the code?

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like libraries like [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) use native iOS and Android code in order to return the applications bundle identifier which means that react-native doesn't provide that in javascript. You could use React Native's [native-modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) API to send the bundle id from Java or Objective C to javascript (they have a section in the linked docs on how to export constant values).

Also here are some snippets from react-native-device-info on how they retrieved the bundle identifier.

On Android (RNDeviceModule.java):

```
String bundleId = this.reactContext.getPackageName();
```

On iOS (RNDeviceInfo.m) - keep in mind idk objective-c so this snippet might not work:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"] ?: [NSNull null]
```

Also if you are using expo currently, then [you can access the app.json file](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants#expoconstantsmanifest) with Expo.Constants:

```
import { Constants } from 'expo';
// this will only work if you specify the bundleIdentifier in app.json
let bundleId = Constants.manifest.ios.bundleIdentifier;
```

Hope this mess of a post somewhat helps! Honestly, it might just be worth it to use a library but it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yeah, we came to similar conclusions about react-native-device-info. We may have to use it, or try to parse out their solution. It's messy, but it might work. I was just hoping someone knew something simpler. No, we aren't using Expo. Thanks for the info.

Comment: This isn't quite what I wanted, but it did the trick and it's what we ended up doing.

Answer (score 13):

on mac you can see it inside **general Tab**
[image]

you can also use

```
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";

console.log("@ device   ",DeviceInfo.getBundleId())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from `DeviceInfo.getVersion()`

replace `getVersion` to the following list according to your need

```
export function getUniqueID(): string;
export function getManufacturer(): string;
export function getDeviceId(): string;
export function getSystemName(): string;
export function getSystemVersion(): string;
export function getBundleId(): string;
export function getBuildNumber(): string;
export function getVersion(): string;
export function getDeviceName(): string;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-fs in your app anyway, you can do the following slightly ugly hack to get your bundle Id:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

getAppBundleIdAndroid = () => 
    RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath.replace(/.+\/(.+?)\/files/, '$1');
```

}